# PHP Imap outlook categories

Tags: php, outlook, exchange-server

I'm working on a script to get emails from IMAP (exchange server). This is working correctly, but I'd like to apply a filter based on "Outlook categories". Please see the image for what I mean.

imap_headerinfo doesnt seem to contain this information. Is there any other way to get this information?

[image: Outlook Categories]

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of those categories, but after a quick Google search it looks to me like that's an Outlook thing, not an IMAP one. As such, "categories" don't exist in IMAP, the only thing you can do is to either have a separate database where you store which mails have been assigned which category or you add a custom header to those mails (such as `X-RoyVanDerSar-Category: blue`).

Unfortunately, Googling for how Outlook does it only reveals trash like tutorials on how to set categories, advertisements for Outlook and sites in bad English advertising "improvements" that look suspiciously like malware.

Comment: thanks for solutuon but if I set category in header, it is not shows me as assigned category, with "X-RoyVanDerSar-Category" header parameter. any suggestion for that ?